# How to filter on a group field in a tablix?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix, ssrs-grouping

I have a tablix in SSRS 2008 R2 which I mean to only display when field value tablix_flag = 2.  My dataset looks like:

```
tablix_flag     ACA_N_ACO_Link2                        Details3
1               CA9CEE16-84FE-418E-933F-33208185A294   C
1               6921FD87-7244-4AB1-934B-471E6B549AA7   A
1               014ED434-4C80-48FF-A93E-95C1051B1638   C
2               6921FD87-7244-4AB1-934B-471E6B549AA7   A
2               6921FD87-7244-4AB1-934B-471E6B549AA7   B
```

As you can see, rows 2 and 4 are identical except for the tablix_flag value.  I want all of the tablix_flag=1 rows to be in tablix1 and the other two in tablix2.  Previously I had an expression to display only tablix_flag=2 records in tablix2, but i have removed this now so that it shows all records, regardless of flag.

This is what my output looks like now:
[image]

[image]

I only want to see the columns where there is a "2" in the first column on the green rows.  So I want to be able to display just these "2" rows, but the problem is that there are 2 groups in my tablix2:

- ACA_N_ACO_Link2
- Details3

As you can see from the above pictures, the "2" rows appear under the "1" parent group.  In other words, from my dataset, there are two parent rows which are identical (2 and 4).  I just want to see row 4 and row 5 in this case.  How can I do this?

The ACA_N_ACO_Link2 group has no filters and no visibility restrictions.  (If it makes a difference, Details3 group does have a filter on it).  But the tablix2 has visibility expression in SSRS:

```
=iif(tablix_flag=2,false,true)
```

But this resulted in 0 records!  Does this make sense what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of worrying about the visibility why not set a 'filter' on your grouping as you did for Details3 group?  A filter by it's definition should be setting things that are set there like a 'where' clause predicate after the dataset has been evaluated.  Either that or take your dataset and completely eliminate out the values you do not want and hard code your dataset to have a predicate of 'where tablix_flag = 2'

There may be more going on if your filter is set on 'Details3' group that is looking to differentiate the different values you could be grouping 'A, B, ' etc...  The key is having each grouping be a different set of child values and the 2nd column appears to repeat for value 4 and 5 and column 3 on both have different values yet you mention having them be together.

I would ensure the set is simple to start and has one filter on a parent group to start of just what you want to determine.  Set it's filter and if you then get expected results add a parent group to that of extra predicates.

Comment: I figured out the problem.  It was simply a matter of grouping on an additional field.  That was all that was needed!